# Can't use "open location" when it's part of a longer script

Tags: applescript, script

The following script works fine to open a URL in my default browser:

```
open location "https://google.com"
```

However, I've got an existing script to grab a URL from my Terminal window to open it in my browser. When I use this script, I get the error "Expected end of line but found identifier" and the variable for my URL was highlighted:

```
use framework "Foundation"

tell application "Terminal"
    set windowContents to the contents of the front window
end tell
set windowContents to current application's class "NSString"'s stringWithString:windowContents
set fidoRegexPattern to "<PATTERN>"
set fidoRegex to current application's class "NSRegularExpression"'s regularExpressionWithPattern:(fidoRegexPattern) options:(0) |error|:(missing value)
set matchRanges to (fidoRegex's matchesInString:(windowContents) options:(0) range:({0, windowContents's |length|()}))'s valueForKey:("range")

set urlStrings to current application's class "NSMutableArray"'s new()
repeat with thisRange in matchRanges
    tell urlStrings to addObject:(windowContents's substringWithRange:(thisRange))
end repeat
-- return urlStrings as list
set urlList to urlStrings as list
set fidoUrl to the last item of urlList
open location fidoUrl
return fidoUrl
```

Even if I try swapping out `fidoUrl` for a URL string literal, I'll get the same error, except it'll say that it found `"` instead of end of line.

Everything else about the script looks fine. If I take out the `open location` line and look at the `return` line's results, it gives me the URL I'm expecting.

Googling around seems to indicate that I might get this error if there's an issue with the script itself, but I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you add a `use statement` to a script,`scripting additions` is no longer added by default. It needs to be re-added.

Add the following after `use framework "Foundation"`

```
 use scripting additions
```

If for some reason you do not want `scripting additions` commands available throughout your entire script,  this following option will work as well.

```
using terms from scripting additions
    open location "https://google.com"
end using terms from
```